# How would I go about web scraping from an interactive map?

Tags: web-scraping

This pertains to this interactive map, https://www.newworld-map.com/?filters=ores

An example is the ores here, how would I go about getting the coordinates of each node? It looks like the html element is a Canvas and I could not for the life of me figure out where it pulls the data from for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show us your code, what have you tried until now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that next OP's question will be more in line with Stackoverflow's guidelines (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), one way to solve this would be to inspect what network calls are being made when page loads, and scrape an eventual API endpoint where the data is pulled from. Like below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

time_stamp = int(time.time_ns() / 1000)

ore_list = []
url = f'https://www.newworld-map.com/markers.json?time={time_stamp}'
ores= requests.get(url).json()['ores']
for ore in ores:
    for x in ores[ore]:
        ore_list.append((ore, x, ores[ore][x]['x'], ores[ore][x]['y']))
df = pd.DataFrame(ore_list, columns = ['Ore', 'Code', 'X_Coord', 'Y_Coord'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Ore Code    X_Coord Y_Coord
0   brimstone   02d1ba070438d53ce5fbb1955cd7d694    7473.096191 8715.674805
1   brimstone   0a50c499af034aeb6f38e011648a2ea8    7471.124512 8709.161133
2   brimstone   0b5b190c31eb3d314d993dd393aadfe8    5670.894043 7862.319336
3   brimstone   0f5c7427c75d80e10f71f9e92ddc4362    5883.601562 7703.445801
4   brimstone   20b0801bdb41c7dafbb1053b43c25bd8    6020.838379 8147.747070
... ... ... ... ...
4260    starmetal   86h 8766.964000 8431.438000
4261    starmetal   86i 8598.688000 8562.974000
4262    starmetal   86j 8586.000000 8211.000000
4263    starmetal   86k 8688.938000 8509.722000
4264    starmetal   86l 8685.827000 8505.694000
4265 rows × 4 columns
```